# VBA determine workbook index and switch to one 'Other' workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have code which runs on one workbook and starts by referencing 1 other open workbook, which could have any name, I want to switch to the other open workbook by using the index number for this reason.

Users could open the workbook containing code first or the other workbook first, so I want to be able to say something like IF index of the active sheet is 1, then Workbooks(2).Activate, but if the index of the active sheet is 2, then Workbooks(1).Activate, thank you.

I have this code to make sure there are only 2 books open already;

```
   If Workbooks.Count > 2 Then
        MsgBox "Have ONLY the new data file and this open before running :)"
        Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Assuming you only have one window open on each, you can just call `activewindow.ActivateNext` to switch from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

To toggle back and forth between two open workbooks in the [Workbooks Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224505%28v=office.11%29.aspx) use some maths against a comparison of the [ActiveWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx) and the [ThisWorkbook Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215773%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

```
Workbooks(IIf(CBool(Workbooks(1).Name = ThisWorkbook.Name), _
              1 - CBool(ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name), _
              2 + CBool(ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name))).Activate
```

This should likely be accompanied by a check to make sure that there are only two workbooks in the queue (as your original sample indicates).

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeeped. So this code should select the other sheet than the one the code is running in? I've put it into my code as below but its throwing out a 400 error;                                      `  Dim MacroSheet As Worksheet
 Set MacroSheet = ActiveSheet
   
 ' THIS PART selects other book
 
Workbooks(IIf(CBool(Workbooks(1).Name = ThisWorkbook.Name), _
              1 + Abs(CBool(ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name)), _
              2 + CBool(ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name))).Activate
 
    Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet
 Set MasterSheet = ActiveSheet `

Comment: No. That activates the alternate workbook when two workbooks are open in a single application instance. If each workbook had only a single worksheet then yes, I suppose your statement could be true but this code is about toggling between two workbooks, not about selecting worksheets.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I put your code in where I want to switch to the other book and then wish to define that sheet as MasterSheet to call back later into the code

Comment: Well, I opened two workbooks into a single application instance and put that code into one of them then ran it repeatedly. It always toggled the activeworkbook back and forth. Then I put the same code into the other workbook and ran it repeatedly. It still toggled the active workbook back and forth. That seemed to be what you were asking about.